# Problem using existing index laws with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to working with complex numbers and am confused about using existing methods of working with indicies.

Consider that:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& x = -1\\
&(\sqrt{x})^{3}=-i\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

I am perfectly comfortable with this result, given that using exponential form and raising to a power of 3/2 gives the same result.

My problem is, if you apply the cube before the square root, you get a different result:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{(x)^{3}}=i
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \text{Since } (-1)^{3} = -1.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

So in this case:

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(\sqrt{x})^{3} \ne \sqrt{x^{3}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Why is this problem introduced and is there an explanation of how to resolve this other than saying the normal rules don't apply? I want to be sure about when I can apply certain operations when working with complex numbers and to this point any new mathematics I have learned is completely consistent with existing rules (meaning you cannot get a false result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: fractional and real exponents applied to complex numbers don't behave the way you expect. Natural-number exponents do. Integer exponents do.

In particular, you've tried to use the rule that 
$$
x^{\frac a b} = (x^a)^\frac1b,
$$
and that one doesn't work in general. That's sort of a pity, but it's also the starting point for a lot of interesting mathematics.

All the other rules you know and love, like
$$
x^{a + b}= x^a \cdot x^b
$$
work fine, too. But just as, for real numbers, $\log$ is defined only on the positive real-axis, so rules like
$$
\log(a^b) = b \log a
$$
only make sense for positive values $a$, for the complexes $\log$ is defined on a larger domain...so things have the potential to be more subtle.

If you want to know what rules apply, one possibility is to work with the actual definitions and *check*.

Comment: Thank you very much. An additional question though: I have seen the use of natural logarithms to find the value of things like i^i, allowing the exponent to be taken out of the logarithm and multiplied. Could you be a little bit more specific as to when logarithms apply?

Comment: If it were 1975, when I took my first complex variables course, I could. Even if it were 1982, when I taught the subject once. But now...no. I'd have to go look stuff up and be really careful, and I've got other things I need to do. And now that *you* know there might be a problem, **you** can look them up too, and it'll do you more good than it'll do me.